# How to use custom emojis in discord.py embeds like this image:

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, embed

## I want to use a custom emoji...

I am developing a discord bot and I would like to import a custom emoji (imported one) in my discord.Embed() but  can not figure out how...

#### How did this bot do it?

[image: this bot uses an emoji :YellowCred: in it's embed]

Take a look at the image above. This bot somehow used an emoji that is not available in the discord emojis list. The developer of this bot definitely used an imported emoji... How can I do the same? I want to use an emoji in my embed. **Do you require Discord Nitro?** Please tell me all I need to know

```
#i tried this and it worked:
embed = discord.Embed(title=":spy: look it's a spy")

#but if i tried this, it does not:
embed = discord.Embed(title=":YellowCred: This is a yellow cred")
```

Some people say to write the id but it still does not work. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: so i have to firstly upload the custom emoji into my server and THEN use the id of the emoji? If the bot is not in a server and i take an emoji from that server (along with it's id), will the emoji work?

Comment: Yes it will, Discord Bots essentially get free Discord Nitro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like : <:emoji_name:emoji_id>
example: <:hello_IADS:98730828398278:
and it will use that but the bot should be in that server where this emoji is added.